# Magento - blank lines being added to wsdl file

Tags: magento

I am trying to call the API but I keep getting a soap error that can't load the file. I found that the reason is there are about 3 blank lines at the top of the XML file that is returned. I found this by doing wget url.

This use to work just fine, when I debug through the API controller the response or xml looks fine all the way through, I don't see any spaces at all. I have no idea what might be causing this. I don't think there is anything we modified that would do this.

UPDATE:: I have found that it appears to be because of an observer class I made for the controller_action_predispatch event. It appears I have some spaces above the

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not completely sure of what I am talking about as far as I've never used the API, but you should try to look at the end of the file which generates your XML for a closing `'?>'`. If there is this closing PHP marker, remove it and try again you API call...

In Magento, PHP file should never be ended by a closing php marker `'?>'`.

edit: as said in comments, also look at spaces before the opening tag `'<?php'`.

Comment: wow, thanks a lot Hugues, it was my file that had the ?>. Why should it never have that and why would the fact the end of my file has that create this issue when it never even got through the call to $client = new SoapClient()

Comment: Oh wait, I might of been wrong, I was trying to access a different wsdl file from a different domain and that worked but then I put my site url for the wsdl and I got the same error again.

Comment: So yeah I am still stuck with this. nothing in magento that generates the response has a ?> in it

Comment: Thanks Hugues, I found that it was a space above <?php in one of my observer classes that get called pre controller dispatch.

Comment: Sorry for this late comment, 
happy to see your problem solve ;)

Answer (score 0):

First thing need to check is api.php file in root folder, most of api blank space issues will come if any empty lines added in api.php file before starting